# How to recode character variable in R with 'unexpected symbol' error

Tags: r, r-car

I want to recode my data from character to numeric. Here is my failed attempt:

```
library(car) # needed for recode
survey1$V16a = recode(survey1$V16, "'Very important'=1; 'Fairly important'=2; 'Not very important'=3; 'Not important at all'=4; 'Can't choose'=99;", as.numeric.result=TRUE)
```

This is the error message I subsequently receive

> Error in recode(survey1$V16, "'Very important'=1; 'Fairly important'=2; 'Not very important'=3; 'Not important at all'=4; 'Can't choose'=99;",  :
>
> in recode term:  'Can't choose'=99
>     message: Error in parse(text = strsplit(term, "=")[[1]][1]) : 
>     :1:7: unexpected symbol
>   1:  'Can't

Comment: try to put \ in front of  `'` in `Can\'t`, This is confusing R

Comment: Please **always** specify what packages you are using. `recode` comes from the `car` package

Comment: @TheRimalaya , please post as answer ...

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to use an extra package such as `car` for this. It also makes the code less readable in my opinion. Just use `ifelse`.

```
survey1$V16a <- ifelse(survey1$V16a == "Very important", 1, 
                ifelse(survey1$V16a == "Fairly important", 2,
                ifelse(survey1$V16a == "Not very important", 3,
                .... )))))
```